# How to change Active Admin input button text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a form in my ActiveAdmin model and I need to translate the content of the button that is generated to upload a file.

I have the following form:

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Details' do
      f.input :orders_file, as: :file
    end
    actions
  end
```

Which displays this:

[image: Form screenshot]

I would like to translate or change that 'Choose file' and 'No file chosen' texts.

I've tried with

```
input_html: { title: 'this', text: 'will', label: 'work', value: 'please' }
```

but no luck.

Thank you!

Comment: ActiveAdmin uses the formtastic gem for forms. Check out their [I18n guide](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#enhanced-localization-formtastic-i18n-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the file upload field labels involves some special techniques invented by Michael McGrady, discussed in detail at https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: Thank you! Turns out the translation will happen by itself when the user uses his browser in a different language. So I don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the file field default labels on buttons and text, they are hard-coded in browsers. Each Browser has its own way to render these things.

[image]

Only way to change these labels is, build your own custom file field control.